# Could Ben Solo have killed Darth Sidious in the same way that Rey did?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-rise-of-skywalker

In the movie *The Rise of Skywalker*, when Ben Solo converted back to the Light Side and became a Jedi again, he would have become capable of channeling all the powers of all the past Jedi, and because of this, he would have been able to deflect Darth Sidious's Force lightning back at him using two lightsabers, just like Rey did.

Is this a correct assumption, or did Rey have something extra that Ben Solo didn't have and would he have most likely failed in an attempt to deflect Force lightning back at Darth Sidious?

Comment: Aside from one of the writers revealing an answer, there's no way of telling. There are significant differences between the two, beginning with Rey never having fallen, and the fact she's Palpatine's grandchild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Probably

We now have two instances of Sheev Palpatine shooting Force lightning and having it blocked with a lightsaber. The first instance was *Revenge of the Sith*, where Mace Windu used his lightsaber to block the force lightning. Palpatine appears to be distressed (and the lightning seems to ricochet back at him, disfiguring him) the more the struggle goes on. It seems like Palpatine will lose until Anakin steps in and cuts Windu's hand off.

[image: Windu vs Palpatine]

Rey does not appear to be any more force adept than Windu (if anything she's less adept). Rey won because [all the Jedi were "with her"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/230904/62709), but there's no reason a redeemed Ben Solo could not have fulfilled that role. As such, it appears anyone who is adept at using The Force can use a lightsaber (or two) to beat back Force lightning.