# Why didn't Palpatine win the standoff with Rey?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

At the end of Rise of Skywalker, we see Palpatine single-handedly almost wipe out an entire fleet of ships. I believe it is the most powerful display of the force in the cinematic universe.

The only thing that stops him is finding out that Rey was still alive. The bolts of lightning were enough to short out a ship, and that was the small tendrils. Imagine what the single tendril could do to a person. Why didn't he just use the same amount of lightning against her? That amount of force lightning would be too much for her to hold back with a lightsaber it would have knocked out of her hands and he would have killed her but no he decided to use a weaker version against her for some reason.

I assume there is a better answer than "the plot demanded it" Because if not... Rise of Skywalker will be my new least favorite movie.

Comment: [Checks novelisation] *something something legions of Jedi supporting her*, I expect.

Comment: *His attack intensified. “You are nothing!” he yelled. “A scavenger girl is no match for the power in me. I am all the Sith!” Her wrist felt like it was going to break. But it wouldn’t. Not today. “And I,” she said, reaching for more strength, for Leia’s lightsaber. It clicked into her hand. “I am all the Jedi.”...."Rey stepped forward, pushing back against his onslaught. Then again. Every step was anguish. It was taking everything the Jedi had given her, everything she had.*"

Comment: This is what I got from that scene: With the power of not one but TWO lightsabers I can kill you.

Comment: @Valorum you're telling me that the voices of the past Jedi kept Palpatine from using his full power against her?

Comment: Apparently. I'm too tired to turn it into an answer.

Comment: Alright, its official The Rise of Skywalker beats  the movie adaptation of Avatar The Last Airbender

Comment: A Jedi Wizard did it.

Comment: @xpert [lolwut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EQldOeZ75gY#t=2m57s)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rey was buoyed up with the power of all the past Jedi. It magnified her abilities and, allied with her lightsaber, made her able to (just) withstand a Sith as powerful as Palpatine.

> He rose from his throne and stepped forward. His eyes glowed with lingering power. “Let your death be the final word in the story of rebellion.” Palpatine reached with his arms, sent Force lightning zagging toward her.
>   She whipped up her lightsaber and blocked it. The impact nearly knocked her from her feet, but she reached for the Force, and stood her ground.
>   His attack intensified. “You are nothing!” he yelled. “A scavenger girl is no match for the power in me. I am all the Sith!”
>   Her wrist felt like it was going to break. But it wouldn’t. Not today.
>   “And I,” she said, reaching for more strength, for Leia’s lightsaber. It clicked into her hand. “I am all the Jedi.”
>   She brought the second lightsaber to bear, crossing its blade with the first, creating an impenetrable shield.
>   Rey stepped forward, pushing back against his onslaught. Then again. Every step was anguish. It was taking everything the Jedi had given her, everything she had.
>   The lightning began to feed back on the Emperor. It ravaged his face, and he tossed back his head in agony, and in denial of what was happening. Rey pursued mercilessly, one foot in front of the other, absorbing power from the Force. Finally, she was ready. She gathered her strength, her faith in the Jedi past, her love of her friends, and she thrust it all at the Emperor.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

The junior novelisation is even more blunt.

> He blasted her with all his anger in the dark side. She crossed the blades and held firm, feeling a thousand presences supporting her. Her blades did more than absorb her grandfather’s energies. They deflected them back at him and the chamber around him.
>   Cracks opened in the walls. The amphitheater began to collapse. Sith acolytes scurried down tunnels. The spiked throne was caught in a stream of energy and exploded.
>   Struck by his own dark power, Palpatine shrieked as his flesh, muscle, and bone melted away, until nothing was left. Not even ash.
>
> <sub><sup>[The Rise of Skywalker: A Junior Novel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: Disney and I must have very different definitions of the term "junior". If *that's* "junior", then I can't wait for the Bambi remake directed by George Romero.